# Pythonic way for max-sum-max multiple lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 3 lists:

```
a1 = range(10)
a2 = range(10,20)
a3 = range(20,30)
```

I need to do the following:

For each list, get max of every 5 element blocks, so hypothetically:

```
a1_maxes = [max1_a1, max2_a1]
a2_maxes = [max1_a2, max2_a2]
a3_maxes = [max1_a3, max2_a3]
```

Sum each "maxes" list, so:

```
for each i:
    sum_i = sum(ai_maxes)
```

Take the max of these 3 sums, so:

```
max(sum_1, sum_2, sum_3)
```

I could not get myself to use `map()` here. What would be the most Pythonic (concise) way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: When you say "get max of every 5 element blocks", do you mean that for `a1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6]`, `a1_maxes = [5 6]`?

Comment: Why not use `numpy.array`?

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 = range(10)
a2 = range(10,20)
a3 = range(20,30)

print(max(sum(x[i:i+5]) for x in (a1,a2,a3) for i in xrange(0,len(a1),5)))
135
```

Just get the `sum`of each chunk `x[i:i+5]`

To make it more obvious, the lists become split into the following chucks:

```
print(list(x[i:i+5]) for x in [a1,a2,a3] for i in xrange(0,len(a1),5))

[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]
```

Then max just gets the largest sum:

If you want the highest two elements from each check:

```
mx_pair = max(sorted(x[i:i+5])[-2:] for x in (a1,a2,a3) for i in xrange(0,len(a1),5))
print(sum(mx_pair))
57
```

If the answer should be 53:

```
from itertools import izip,imap
def chunks(l):
    for i in xrange(0,len(l), 5):
        yield l[i:i+5]

sums = (max(izip(*ele)) for ele in imap(chunks,(a1,a2,a3)))
print(sum(max(sums)))
```

Comment: I think the output should be 53 not 135.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, do you mean 57?

Comment: Nop 53, 24 + 29 from a3.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, what about 28 and 29? The OP wants the two highest values from each chuck of five elements. `a1_maxes = [max1_a1, max2_a1]`

Comment: I don't think OP is considering overlapping groups. So, from the two groups `[(20, 21, 22, 23, 24), (25, 26, 27, 28, 29)]` 53 should be the answer. But may be you're right :-), OP should clarify this.

Comment: I definitely got the answer as 53 by following the OP. This answer doesn't seem to be obtained using the OP's algorithm.

Comment: @DarrenRinger, well I will wait to see what the OP decides, it is not totally clear, especially considering  the comment `a1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6], a1_maxes become  `[5 6]`

Comment: Seems clear to me, [1 2 3 4 5 6] groups as [(1 2 3 4 5) (6)], the maxes are [5 6] and their sum is 11.  The ranges listed yield maxes of [4 9] [14 19] [24 29], sums of 13, 33, and 53, and the maximum of the sums thereby yielded is 53 :\

Comment: @DarrenRinger, well I have covered pretty much every possibility

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this into pieces.

The first point is that you probably don't want separate `a1`, `a2`, and a3` variables; if you're going to have to do the exact same thing repeatedly to multiple values, and then iterate over those values, they probably belong in a list. So:

```
a = [a1, a2, a3]
```

Now, how do you split an iterable into 5-element pieces? There are a number of ways to do it, from [the `grouper` function in the `itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to zipping slices to iterating over slices. I'll use `grouper`:

```
grouped = [grouper(sublist, 5) for sublist in a]
```

Now we just want the max value of each group, so:

```
maxes = [[max(group) for group in sublist] for sublist in a]
```

And now, we want to sum up each sublist:

```
sums = [sum(sublist) for sublist in maxes]
```

And finally, we want to take the max of these sums:

```
maxsum = max(sums)
```

Now, given that each of these list comprehensions is only being used as a one-shot iterable, we might as well turn them into generator expressions. And if you want to, you can merge some of the steps together:

```
maxsum = max(sum(max(group) for group in grouper(sublist, 5)) for sublist in a)
```

And, having done that, you don't actually need `a` to be created explicitly, because it only appears once:

```
maxsum = max(sum(max(group) for group in grouper(sublist, 5)) 
             for sublist in a1, a2, a3)
```

Comment: Couple of issues: `grouped = [grouper(sublist, 5) for sublist in a]
`, `[[max(group) for group in sublist] for sublist in grouped]`,  `sums = [sum(sublist) for sublist in maxes]`...

Comment: I am looking for a Python 2.7 solution. `grouper` is Python >= 3 I believe.

Comment: @SandeepY Grouper recipe is present in Python 2.7 as well: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes

Comment: @SandeepY: Why would you just assume that something doesn't exist in 2.7 without just looking at the docs to see? Or trying it? Especially since this is code in a recipe, so it doesn't even _matter_ if the recipe is in the 2.7 docs; if you copy the 3.x recipe into a Python 2.7 interpreter or script it works just fine.